# On change of select not triggered in wordpress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to trigger an onchange ajax query but it is not working. In the beginning I am changing some innerHTML, then populate a  through an ajax query before the user can select any dropdown lists. Finally I want to trigger an on change of location to make another ajax query. Unfortunately the code is not working. All code is in one test.js file

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var locationDiv = document.getElementById('locations-ddl');
    var selectionDivLoc = locationDiv.querySelector('.wpv-custom-search-filter__input');
    selectionDivLoc.innerHTML = '<select id="location" name="location"></script>';

    var repositoryDiv = document.getElementById('repositories-ddl');
    var selectionDivRep = repositoryDiv.querySelector('.wpv-custom-search-filter__input');
    selectionDivRep.innerHTML = '<select id="repository" name="repository"></script>';

    var fondDiv = document.getElementById('fonds-ddl');
    var selectionDivFond = fondDiv.querySelector('.wpv-custom-search-filter__input');
    selectionDivFond.innerHTML = '<select id="fond" name="fond"></script>';

    var seriesDiv = document.getElementById('series-ddl');
    var selectionDivSeries = seriesDiv.querySelector('.wpv-custom-search-filter__input');
    selectionDivSeries.innerHTML = '<select id="series" name="series"></script>';




  $.ajax({
      
      'url' : ajaxurl,
      data: {
          'action':'get_locations', // This is our PHP function below
      
      },
      success:function(data) {
  // This outputs the result of the ajax request (The Callback)
          $("#location").replaceWith(data);
      },
      error: function(errorThrown){
          window.alert(errorThrown);
      }
  });
    



 jQuery('#location').change(function(){
    window.alert('yep');
    $.ajax({
      
      'url' : ajaxurl,
      data: {
          'action':'test', // This is our PHP function below
      
      },
      success:function(data) {
            window.alert(data);
      },
      error: function(errorThrown){
          window.alert(errorThrown);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: `$("#location").replaceWith(data)`- you are replacing the existing `#location` element with a new one here, so any event handlers you had already bound to that element, will get lost at this point. (And you _did_ bind yours previously to this, because the AJAX request is asynchronous.) Use _event delegation_.

Comment: the replacement also has the same id of location. Does that make a difference?

Comment: No, it does not. Whether you replace an element with one with the same ID, or something completely different, changes nothing about the fact, _that_ the original has been replaced. `jQuery('#location').change` does not bind the event handler "to" the ID, it binds it to the element it _currently_ finds under that ID, at this point. Remove an element, and you remove all the event handlers that were registered for it as well.

Comment: To add, you seem to be using vanilla javascript while employing the jQuery library. var locationDiv=document.getElementById('locations-ddl'); in jQuery this is var locationDiv=$("#locations-ddl");